# How to save string and array in the same row into csv by using python?

Tags: python

I have a vector, it is `np.array([[1,2,3]])`.

I want to save the vector and the name of the vector in the same row.

For example

Vector1 1 2 3

Vector2 4 5 6

Vector3 7 8 9

Then, I have ever tried like this

```
import csv
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3]])
b='Vector1'
c=[b,a]
with open ('testfile.csv','ab') as fxx:
        w=csv.writer(fxx)
        for row in c:
            w.writerow(row)
```

the result is
[image]

then I also have tried this

```
import csv
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3]])
b='Vector1'
c=np.append(b,a)
with open ('testfile3.csv','ab') as fxx:
        w=csv.writer(fxx)
        for row in c:
            w.writerow(row)
```

And then the result is
[image]

But the result what I want is
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3]])
b='Vector1'
c=np.append(b,a)
print(c)
with open ('testfile3.csv','a') as fxx:
        w=csv.writer(fxx)
        w.writerow(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[1, 2, 3]]
b = 'Vector1'
a[0].append(b)
print(a)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

output:

```
 0  1  2        3
0  1  2  3  Vector1
```

Answer (score 0):

`writerow()` expects a sequence where each element will fill a column, ie

```
`writer.writerow(["foo", 42, "bar")
```

will result in (quoting and delimiter depending on your writer params):

```
"foo",42,"bar"
```

In your code you create a list `c` as:

```
c=['Vector1', [[1, 2, 3]]]
```

ie your first element is a string and the second a list of one element which is another list.

then iterate over this list to pass each of it's elements to your writer, so basically what you're doing is:

```
writer.writerow("Vector1")
writer.writerow([[1, 2, 3]])
```

For the first line, since strings are sequences, it will fill one column per character resulting in (quoting and delim depending on your writer config) :

```
"V","e","c","t","o","r","1"
```

and for the second, since you pass a list of one element, it will fill one single column with the string representation of the single element in the list:

```
"[1, 2, 3]"
```

If what you want is

```
"Vector1",1,2,3
```

then the obvious solution is to pass the correct sequence to `writerow`:

```
writer.writerow(["Vector1", 1, 2, 3])
```

Now you just have to change your code to correctly produce this sequence...